# Odoo assets not loading

Tags: odoo, assets

I have an ODOO application that runs fine in general circumstances. I am trying to host DB to another server.

I am creating and backup of DB and uploading it to my cloud SQL. I changed the DB name and Uploaded backup data from local DB and then. I am using this configuration to start server:

```
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
admin_passwd = mb_staging
db_host = my-ip
db_port = 5432
db_user = odoo
db_password = ....
;addons_path = ....
addons_path = ....
logfile = /var/log/odoo/odoo12.log
;dbfilter=db_name
xmlrpc_port=8069
longpolling_port = 8072
proxy_mode = True
```

I am running this configuration and I am getting to choose DB and select the DB name but I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: odoo.define is not a function
```

I am unable to load any assets. Is there any way I can generate new assets or change the path.

There is one file inside this folder:

```
~/.local/share/Odoo/filestore/db_name
```

I don't know how to generate asset files and which file I need to copy to which folder.

When I am running odoo using default conf with false everything. It works fine.

Where can I find the assets folder for default? Inside this:

```
~/.local/share/Odoo/filestore
```

There is one folder my moved new db name.

Answer (score 7):

A chance to recreate the assets attachments is to delete the attachments and then restarting the Odoo server.

`DELETE FROM ir_attachment WHERE name ilike '%assets%';`

Comment: Yes in postgres by using PgAdmin or psql, on the moved/copied db.

Comment: Probably there is something more than just assets

Comment: There is a file called ~/.local/share/Odoo/filestore/db-name where is the default assets. When I am running odoo with default db.

Comment: That's where all attachments are saved.

Comment: Do you where odoo store default assets file so that I can copy to new db folder name.